# Selenium stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I got this error when I tried to click on a dropdown id:

```
stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

I'm thinking to use this code:

```
boolean staleElement = true;
        while(staleElement)
        {
            try{
                WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
                WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(dropDownId));
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
                element.click();
                staleElement = false;
            }
            catch(StaleElementReferenceException e)
            {
                staleElement = true;
                Thread.sleep(200);
            }
        }
```

Is there some way to prevent infinite loop or better way to click on the id after I get this exception?

Comment: Your code here is quite good. You can add some kind of counter so if you couldn't click the element in, say, 10 attempts to fail the test.

Comment: I just run it and I got `is not clickable at point (464, 465). Other element would receive the click:`

Comment: Try using `visibilityOfElementLocated` instead of `elementToBeClickable`. Also you can add a short wait after the `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(element));` before clicking the element

Comment: Please paste it as a answer so I can rate it.

Comment: @PeterPenzov Done. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally your code is quite good. To avoid infinite loop you can add some kind of counter there so as in case of, say, 10 failed attempts to click the element to fail the test.
In case you get `Element is not clickable at point` exception inside the `try` block you can try using `visibilityOfElementLocated` Expected Conditin instead of `elementToBeClickable`.
In case this is still not enough you can add a short delay between the `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(element));` and `element.click();` commands to let the elements be finally rendered on the page before clicking the element.